# Most Effective Way to Sync a ParseObject with Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, synchronization

I'm currently using Parse.com for my Cloud processing needs in my Android app and I'm trying to figure out the best way to get live updates to ParseObjects via the Parse server. I'd rather not have to get my entire query of ParseObjects every time I want to update the local data with live data (seems very inefficient) as Parse seems to suggest with the use of cached queries.

I already have the BroadcastReceiver and Services in place needed to get Push Notifications from the Parse server but since these always pop up a message I'd rather not go this route either. I already have a sync adapter in place to resolve any conflicts between local and server data so I just need a way to tell my app that an update has been made to a particular ParseObject so it can get updates for that object only (and tell my ContentResolver an update has been made).

**EDIT:**
Below is the code I've tried using what Parse suggests in it's documentation. This code still sends a Notification object to the notification bar even if the 'title' and 'alert' tags in the JSONObject have no values or blank values.

```
//custom notification data
JSONObject pushObj = new JSONObject();
try {
    pushObj.put("notifVal", "TestValue");
}
catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    Log.i(TAG, "Error creating Push Notification JSONObject");
    return;
}
//Parse notification object
ParsePush pPush = new ParsePush();
pPush.setData(pushObj);
ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getQuery();
pPush.setQuery(query);
pPush.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if(e == null)
            Log.i(TAG,"Push Notification Sent");
        else
            Log.i(TAG,"Push Notification Error");
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2:**
Simply enough all that I was missing was an action tag in the JSONObject...

```
pushObj.put("action", "com.parse.example.UPDATE");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep a last check date in your shared preferences that way when you get a push all you have to do is query against created date and updated date of the object to see either are greater than your last check date. Doing that will then only give you the new or updated items since you last checked

Comment: I already have a Content provider which actually holds the last updated date and the object ID. I'm not having any problems resolving conflicts but I'm trying to get Parse to send out some sort of notification for my BroadcastReceiver (probably with Parse Cloud code) to tell it to update across devices. Right now the only solution Parse offers are Push Notifications which pop up a Notification on the users status bar each update.

Comment: You can provide a custom push that does not show a notification. Read through the documentation about pushes again and you will see what i mean. Basically parse looks for a title and if there isnt one it does not display the notification in the notification bar

Comment: According to Parse's documentation you can customize your notification using a JSONObject as the data sent. ([Parse Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android) ---> Sending Options ---> Customizing Your Notifications). I've tried implementing what they say will work (not setting the 'title' and 'alert' values) but Parse replaces these values with defaults with the app name as the 'title' and "Notification Received" as the 'alert'. I've also tried setting these values to blank but all I get is a blank notification. I'll update my question with the code I'm using.

Comment: you need to set a custom action in your json

Comment: I was able to get the notification intent to pop up. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a syncadapter you have a few options:

Manually sync periodically using android d sync service

Write a custom notification receiver that does not show the notification.

Implement a realtime MQ between parse and your app. Trigger it using parse cloud code or similar.

Could be more but these are the first that come to mind.

Comment: Syncing periodically is something already created in my app but since it involves getting all my objects at once, it's something I want to use sparingly (like once every 8-12 hours). Writing a custom notification receiver with no notification I sounds like the best option right now. I haven't found any mention of how to implement this though. Do you have any examples?

Comment: The parse docs have an example of a custom broadcast receiver for this use: https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving/Android

Essentially, you implement a custom BroadcastReceiver and grab the Intent where you can decide to show a notification or not AND perform any extra work if you desire (such as sync).